# How do I limit synchronisation to certain files with a WinSCP command line call?

Tags: winscp

I use the following command line as a shortcut on my desktop so that I can just dbl-click it and download my backups (which the server does nightly and adds to the remote dir):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe" /defaults "1 and 1"  /synchronize // "C:\files\_backup_sync" /backups
```

How would I now add a filemask to it so that it, for example, only downloads a certain set of files. Eg something akin to this (this doesn't work of course):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe" /defaults "1 and 1"  /synchronize // "C:\files\_backup_sync" /backups/RGraph.*.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`/rawtransfersettings IncludeFileMask`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/rawtransfersettings#includefilemask):

```
/rawtransfersettings IncludeFileMask="RGraph.*.js"
```